# Some Issues with flexible css box model

Tags: javascript, css, subdomain

I am using flexible css box model in one of my web application. For cross browser compatibility in IE, I am using the flexie.js pollyfill. I have got it working perfectly fine on my local machine as well as on my production environment. However, the problem starts when i try to serve my static files( css, javascript and images) from a subdomain instead of the naked domain. The flexie.js file is loaded in ie, however it doesn't seem to do anything when i serve static content through sub-domain. As soon as i change my config to use naked domain for serving the page, flexie.js renders the page appropriately. I don't see any ajax in play here and all my other script files work perfectly fine when i use the subdomain.  I don't think this makes any sense, and am sure there is some other reason for the same.

Comment: Do you have an example? If you're using url() in css, please note that the path is relative to your css file, not the html file.

Comment: if you're having problems when serving from a separate subdomain then you may be hitting issues with the browser's security model trying to prevent cross-site scripting attacks. But that's just speculation; without seeing it in action, it's not going to be possible to know for sure.

Comment: @Spuldey: as far as i have read, browser doesnt allow ajax requests to be made over subdomains, however flexie.js  is a pollyfill that essentially mimics the box model in earlier browsers and hence i don't think it makes any ajax request.

Comment: @Eliasdx: I am not using any url in my css files. also currently i can't provide you the link to the website. However i am updating the question to provide some more details

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a limitation of flexie.js (which gets its CSS parsing from selectivizr) is that the static files and webpage must be on the exact same domain:

http://selectivizr.com/#things
(linked from https://github.com/doctyper/flexie)

> Style sheets MUST be hosted on the same domain as the page due to browser security restrictions. Likewise, style sheets loaded using the file: protocol will not work.